# Could not resolve de.measite.minidns:minidns:[0.1,0.2)

Tags: java, android, maven

I am quite new into Android World. I have added SMACK 4.1.0 for developing XMPP connectivity. While trying to build app, got below errors consistently. Tried googling but no fruitful results. Kindly provide your help.

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve de.measite.minidns:minidns:[0.1,0.2).
>   Required by:bind:app:unspecified > org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0 > org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-minidns:4.1.0
>   Failed to list versions for de.measite.minidns:minidns.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/measite/minidns/minidns/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/measite/minidns/minidns/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   peer not authenticated

```
Build.Gradle(Project:bind) file is :-
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to    
all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {
   repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
    jcenter()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
  }

 allprojects {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  }

 Build.Gradle(Module:app) file is :-
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sukeshsaxena.bind"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     
  'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
   }

  dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
      //Smak config for XMPP over TCP
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0"
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0"

    }
```

Let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newest version of

`de.measite.minidns:minidns` is `0.1.7`

`org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-minidns` is `4.1.3`.

Try to use

```
de.measite.minidns:minidns:0.1.7
org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-minidns:4.1.3
```

in your gradle file.

Comment: Thnx for helping me over here. I perform some 16 packages installations as recommended by Android SDK Manager. Post then problem get resolved. Just one query if I need to place the two lines you mentioned above, Should I place in Buid.Gradle (Module : app) under dependencies? Again Thnx for helping me & provide guidance

Comment: I have come across other problem. I am trying to connect to Open Server installed locally through Emulator. I kept host as 127.0.0.1 and port as 9090. I am getting following error org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '127.0.0.1:9090' failed because java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 9090) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: @SukeshSaxena you should check if port 9090 is opened. Easily type telnet 127.0.0.1 9090 for checking

Comment: Got error of minidns again put two line suggested in dependencies of gradle (Module:App) file but error still persist

Comment: Hey how did you resolve this error. I am stuck on the same thing.

Comment: I get this error today. it works fine 2 weeks ago :(( I already use 4.1. version of smack

Comment: seems there is no minidns on maven repository!